# Why do I get "overflow evaluating the requirement" when rewriting a function using Diesel's traits into a trait method?

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I am trying to add pagination using Diesel. The compiler is able to check bounds on a generic type if I use a function but isn't if I try to do the same as an implementation of a trait.

This is a simple working example:

```
use diesel::query_dsl::methods::{LimitDsl, OffsetDsl};

pub fn for_page<T>(query: T)
where
    T: OffsetDsl,
    T::Output: LimitDsl,
{
    query.offset(10).limit(10);
}
```

[`OffsetDsl`](https://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/query_dsl/methods/trait.OffsetDsl.html) and 
[`LimitDsl`](https://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/query_dsl/methods/trait.LimitDsl.html) are Diesel's traits which provides the methods `offset` and `limit`.

When I try to extract this method as a trait and implement it like this

```
use diesel::query_dsl::methods::{LimitDsl, OffsetDsl};

trait Paginator {
    fn for_page(self);
}

impl<T> Paginator for T
where
    T: OffsetDsl,
    <T as OffsetDsl>::Output: LimitDsl,
{
    fn for_page(self) {
        self.offset(10).limit(10);
    }
}
```

I get a not very clear error message.

```
error[E0275]: overflow evaluating the requirement `<Self as diesel::query_dsl::offset_dsl::OffsetDsl>::Output`
 --> src/main.rs:3:1
  |
3 | / trait Paginator {
4 | |     fn for_page(self);
5 | | }
  | |_^
  |
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Paginator` for `Self`
note: required by `Paginator`
 --> src/main.rs:3:1
  |
3 | trait Paginator {
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0275]: overflow evaluating the requirement `<Self as diesel::query_dsl::offset_dsl::OffsetDsl>::Output`
 --> src/main.rs:4:5
  |
4 |     fn for_page(self);
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Paginator` for `Self`
note: required by `Paginator`
 --> src/main.rs:3:1
  |
3 | trait Paginator {
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I understand that this means that the compiler cannot check the condition on `T::Output`, but it's not clear what is the difference with a simple function with the same condition.

I'm using Rust 1.35.0 and Diesel 1.4.

Comment: Does it work if you use `T::Output: LimitDsl` instead of `<T as OffsetDsl>::Output: LimitDsl`? I tried to [reproduce the issue in rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2fb3f14df86a48bdd309a196a72c390a) but it seems to work fine - diesel doesn't seem to be supported in the playground so I haven't tried testing it with the real library yet

Comment: what version/edition of rust are you using and which channel? Also which version of diesel?

Comment: Nope. :(  I guess it might have something to do with the way how Diesel define these traits, but I cannot figure out how.

Comment: The constraint solver in the Rust compiler can sometimes be a bit fragile – see also [this question on URLO](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/weird-compiler-issue-overflow-evaluating-the-requirement/27051) for another example.

Comment: You could try restricting your implementation to certain types instead of all `OffsetDsl`s? [Have a look at how `LimitDsl` is implemented for `Table` for example](https://docs.diesel.rs/src/diesel/query_dsl/limit_dsl.rs.html#18-28) - it's similar to your `Paginator` but defines Output in the body and relative to the input type

Comment: > You could try restricting your implementation to certain types instead of all OffsetDsl


I think the problem is with a bound on `T::Output: `.   If I remove this line (and a cal of .limit function) it works fine.

Comment: I am sorry about multiple comments.  Cannot get used to the fact that SO sends comment on Enter.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Thanks for the link. Yes, I've read a lot of threads about this error.  I just don't understand why the solver behaves differently for a generic function and trait.

Comment: @Max Did you see the bit that adding and removing and unrelated, unused import changes whether the error occurs in the other question? This is why I posted it – it shows that the behaviour appears to be completely random, and can't be reasoned about without understand the implementation details of the compiler.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Yes I did.  I thought about filling a bug in rust itself. They say that if rustc error message is not clear enough it should be considered as a bug, and I would say that this message is definitely not clear enough. 

 Problem is that I cannot come up with a minimal example. I tried to reproduce it with my traits instead of ones from Diesel, but with main it works perfectly.

Comment: @Max I have the same problem, if I build with Diesel's traits, it fails, but with my own it's fine. It might be related to [this rustc bug](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/34260) which I found from [this other filed bug](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/47032) - it seems to be unresolved

Comment: I still don't understand why but the solution suggested by Shepmaster works.  Thanks for your answers, guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot answer *why* they differ. I can say that repeating the bounds on the trait definition compiles:

```
use diesel::query_dsl::methods::{LimitDsl, OffsetDsl};

trait Paginator
where
    Self: OffsetDsl,
    Self::Output: LimitDsl,
{
    fn for_page(self);
}

impl<T> Paginator for T
where
    T: OffsetDsl,
    T::Output: LimitDsl,
{
    fn for_page(self) {
        self.offset(10).limit(10);
    }
}
```

You may also be interested in the [extending Diesel guide](http://diesel.rs/guides/extending-diesel/), which discusses how best to add a `paginate` method.

Comment: It works! Thank you! Should have try it myself. It's a bit strange though, because in this case I can implement this method inside trait definition and I don't need an implementation at all. 
Thanks for the link! I've read it, but it seems a bit overcomplicated for a simple task I want it to do.